# compile error c++ standard filestream

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::ifstream ifs;
    std::ofstream ofs;
    std::string input;

    // ask for input file and output file
    std::cout << "Enter input file name: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> input;
    ifs.open(input);
    if (ifs.fail()) {
        std::cout << "Failed to open the input file." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Enter output file name: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> input;
    ofs.open(input);
    if (ofs.fail()) {
        std::cout << "Failed to open the output file for write access." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // read the count of node and link
    int node_count = 0;
    int link_count = 0;
    ifs >> node_count;
    ifs >> link_count;

    // alloc and zero memory
    int *nodes = new int[node_count];
    int *links = new int[link_count];
    for (int i = 0; i < node_count; ++i) { nodes[i] = 0; }
    for (int i = 0; i < link_count; ++i) { links[i] = 0; }

    while (!ifs.eof()) {
        bool gg = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < link_count; ++i) {
            ifs >> links[i];
            nodes[(links[i] / 10) - 1] = 1;
            nodes[(links[i] % 10) - 1] = 1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < node_count; ++i) {
            if (nodes[i] == 0) {
                gg = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!gg) {
            for (int i = 0; i < link_count; ++i) {
                ofs << links[i] << " ";
            }
            ofs << std::endl;
        }
    }
    delete[] nodes;
    delete[] links;
    ifs.close();
    ofs.close();
}
```

when i compile this c++ program and run got this error.no matching call to std::basicifstream::open(st...,can someone help me on this?is it something i should not use std::? and also straight use the ifs straight

Comment: When posting questions about build errors, please include the *complete* build error, in full and unedited. As text, and formatted as code. Also please point out *where* in the code you get the error(s), with e.g. a comment.

Comment: `ofs.open(input.c_str());` or `-std=c++11`